# The Swift Tour in Apple's Swift Programming Language - the interestingNumber iterated 8 times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Code

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

var smallest = 0

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > smallest {
            smallest = number
        }
    }
}

print(smallest)
```

Link: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1

Running the codes in XCode playground, it shows that it is iterated 8 times.
Looking at the numbers in the array, there are 12 different numbers - 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16,25. So, shouldn't it be 12 times instead?

Comment: The inner loop has iterated 17 times and outer loop 3 times. The If condition inside the inner loop is executed 8 times only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first outer loop iteration, "kind" would be "Prime" and "numbers" would be [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

So In below condition the if condition will be true

- > Prime
- 2 > 0
- 3 > 2
- 5 > 3
- 7 > 5
- 11 > 7
- 13 > 11
- > Fibonacci

In the second outer loop iteration, "kind" would be "Fibonacci" and "numbers" would be [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]

but this time "smallest" is 13 which is greater than all numbers of above array so the if condition would not be executed for this iteration.

- > Square

In the third outer loop iteration, "kind" would be "Square" and "numbers" would be [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

So In below condition the if condition will be true

- 16 > 13
- 25 > 16

So playground shows that code inside if condition was iterated 8 times.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down the sequence of execution so I can visualise it. But I don't understand what  Prime and Square mean here. Can you pls elaborate? Also, what I see is 1>0 2>1 3>2 4>3 5>4 7>5 8>7 9>8 11>9 13>11 16>13 25>16. So isn't it executed 12 times?

Comment: Prime and square both are just a keys of the dictionary which has an array as a value.

Comment: But what I see is 1>0 2>1 3>2 4>3 5>4 7>5 8>7 9>8 11>9 13>11 16>13 25>16. So isn't it executed 12 times?

Comment: I get it now! Because I missed the nature of for-in statement. It runs in SEQUENCE. So there's no comparison run for Fibonacci because the last number of Prime (13) is bigger than any number of Fibonacci. And the iteration continues on to Square in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at which line is executed 8 times:

[image]

The line `smallest = number` inside the if statement.

For that line to be executed, the if condition must be true. And it is true for 8 times, when `number` equals to:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16, 25
```

That's why it's 8 times.